# Python - combination of "AND" and "NOT IN" won't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm currently practicing on recursion and growing lists. However, I encountered an error where both "AND" and "NOT IN" functions won't work. It keeps on returning True regardless of the outcome.
Based on the code, this line:
if (a not in routeList) and (b not in routeList):
won't work.

Here's my Input and Output:

You are currently in LGA airport.

Here are the airports
['BIG', 'CDG', 'GGG', 'DEL', 'DOH', 'DSM', 'EWR', 'EYW', 'HND', 'ICN', 'JFK', 'LGA', 'LHR', 'ORD', 'SAN', 'SFO', 'SIN', 'TLV', 'BUD']

-What's your destination? SIN

count: 0

a CDG

routeList [['CDG']]

count: 1

a FFF

routeList [['CDG'], ['FFF']]

count: 2

b CDG

routeList [['CDG'], ['FFF'], ['CDG']]

The last array ['CDG'] should not be included on the current routeList because it already exists. How can I fix this?

```
#You must return the shortest path in any airports.
#The starting Airport should be in LGA

#List of Airports
airports = ['BIG', 'CDG', 'GGG', 'DEL', 'DOH', 'DSM', 'EWR', 'EYW', 'HND', 'ICN', 'JFK', 'LGA', 'LHR', 'ORD', 'SAN', 'SFO', 'SIN', 'TLV', 'BUD']

#This is the airport routes
routes = [
    ['BGI', 'LGA'],
    ['CDG', 'BUD'],
    ['CDG', 'SIN'],
    ['DEL', 'CDG'],
    ['DEL', 'DOH'],
    ['DSM', 'ORD'],
    ['EWR', 'HND'],
    ['EYW', 'LHR'],
    ['FFF', 'SIN'],
    ['HND', 'ICN'],
    ['HND', 'JFK'],
    ['ICN', 'JFK'],
    ['JFK', 'LGA'],
    ['LHR', 'SFO'],
    ['ORD', 'BGI'],
    ['SAN', 'EYW'],
    ['SFO', 'DSM'],
    ['SFO', 'SAN'],
    ['SIN', 'CDG'],
    ['TLV', 'DEL'],
    ]

startingAirport = 'LGA'

routeList = []
tempList = []


def checkRoute(startPt):
    global routes
    global routeList
    global startingAirport

    tempList = []

    
    count1 = 0
    for i in routes:
        if startPt in i:
            a,b = i
            
            if (a not in routeList) and (b not in routeList):# == True:
            #if (a,b) not in routeList:
            
            
                print('count: %d' %count1)
                if (a != startPt):# and (a not in routeList):
                    tempList.append(a)
                    print('a', a)
                elif b != startPt:# and (b not in routeList):
                    tempList.append(b)
                    print('b', b)
                count1+=1

            routeList.append(tempList[:])
            print('routeList',routeList)
            tempList.clear()
            
def main():
    print(len(routes))
    print("You are currently in %s airport.\n" % startingAirport)
    print("Here are the airports")
    print(airports)
    userIn = input("What's your destination? ")
    if userIn not in airports:
        print("\nThis Airport name is not listed. Please try again")
        main()
    else:
        checkRoute(userIn)

main()
```

Comment: What is the actual code you're running?  You have a bunch of stuff commented out and it seems like your question is about some of the commented-out lines.  Should we uncomment *all* the code before trying to run it and reproduce your problem?

Comment: I don't see any recursion in this code.

Comment: If you put parentheses `()` everywhere to insure your desired logic, does it work then?

Comment: Learn to abstract the actual problem you are working on. Learn to boil down your code to the essentials to demonstrate a problem you have. Most of the time, that will solve the problem for you already. Don't just dump code online for others to fix.

Comment: I was about to add the recursion, however, when I divided my code and group them by chunks, I noticed a semantic error on my lists.

Comment: @jarmod: Doh! Unfortunately there is :-(  In `main()`

Comment: @quamrana ha ha, you're right. That was unexpected.

Comment: @jarmod: Sadly all too frequent.

Comment: I added those hashtags for you to see my previous revisions or incremental changes. However, I'm stuck with this problem:
if (a not in routeList) and (b not in routeList):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the string `'CDG'` does not equal the array `['CDG']`

It's a little messy but I trust you can clean it up:

```
        if ([a] not in routeList) and ([b] not in routeList):
            count1+=1
            print('count: %d' %count1)
            if (a != startPt):
                tempList.append(a)
                print('a', a)
            elif b != startPt:
                tempList.append(b)
                print('b', b)
            routeList.append(tempList[:])
            print('routeList',routeList)
        tempList.clear()
```

Comment: @ExCode You can also use `if ([a] not in routeList) and ([b] not in routeList):`